# CSS Error - Div background not changing

Tags: html, css, layout

I've got a bit of an issue with my CSS. I have a layout that I am trying to use but the background of contentHolder, which has to sub divs menu_left and PageHolder. If I have .PageContent {float: left;} the backgound disapears but I remove the 'float:left;' from both divs the background shows as I want. Does anyone have any ideas.

I have posted my HTML File here to help.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Layout Testing</title>
<style>
body
{
    background-color:#003;
}
    .Page
        {
            width: 80%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        }
    #Heading h1
    {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .contentHolder
    {
        background: white;
        position: inherit;
        clear:both;
    }
    #Menu_Left
    {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
    .PageContent
    {
        float:left;
        width: 70%;
        position: static;
    }

 </style>
 </head>

<body>
    <div class="Page">
        <div id="Heading">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
        </div>
    <div class="contentHolder">
        <div id="Menu_Left">
        </div>
        <div class="PageContent">
        <h2>content</h2>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the floats. (not applying clear: both to the parent holder that won't work)

There are a few ways.

1) You can make this:

```
.contentHolder { overflow: hidden; }
```

2) Make a clear div and add it after .PageContent:

CSS:

```
.clear { clear: both; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: 9999px; height: 0; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="contentHolder">
    <div id="Menu_Left">
    </div>
    <div class="PageContent">
    <h2>content</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

3) Make a clearfix class and add it to the parent:

CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="contentHolder clearfix">
    <div id="Menu_Left">
    </div>
    <div class="PageContent">
    <h2>content</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you float `PageContent` left, it means all elements within `contentHolder` are being floated, so it's height becomes 0 and you don't see the background. You need to make `contentHolder` clear all floats within itself so that it's height expands to the height of the tallest floated element within it.

Add an overflow to `contentHolder` to make it self-clear any elements floated within it.

```
.contentHolder {
    overflow: auto;
}
```